# Extracting a substring from a string of arbitrary length

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have just a hair over 30,000 `tweets`. I have one column that has the actual `tweet`. There are two things that I would like to accomplish with this column.

First here is a snippet of sample data:

```
RT @Just_Sports: Cool page for fans of early pro #baseball. https://t.co/QCMYFQNSq8 #mlb #vintage #Chicago #Detroit #Boston #Brooklyn #Philâ€¦
@brettjuliano you already know #unity #newengland #hiphop #boston #watertown  #network
```

I have a column that uses the following formula to see if the message starts out with `RT` meaning a `re-tweet`. It returns 1 for yes and 0 for no.

What I would like to accomplish is to create a formula in two columns. One that will get the username if the RT column has a value of 1 and in the second column the username if the RT column has a value of 0. Since usernames are of arbitrary length I am unsure of how to go about this.

Example

```
RT @Just_Sports:     |     1     |     @Just_Sports     |     0
@brettjuliano        |     0     |                      |     @brettjuliano
```

Comment: hi @Gaffi I am not using VBA, I am trying to accomplish this via =some_formula

Comment: Press `F1` from Excel. Check out the formula `Search`. If the position of `RT` is always in the begining then you can also use `LEFT`

Comment: Forgive me, I read 'formula' as 'function'. :-)

Comment: Use vlookup, there are mutliple questions and answers on this.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thank you for that suggestion, I was able to do it that way as well

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator: Awesome! I already had the formula ready with me and I could have posted the solution but I wanted you to try it first and post the formula that you tried in case you got an error. ;) The happiness that you get when you solve a problem on your own is simply out of this world ;)

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator: One tip though. I am not that active on twitter nor have I ever Re-Tweeted any tweet so I am not sure how `RT` works. The reason why I suggested `SEARCH` and not `FIND` is because `FIND` is case-sensitive. Besides this, if you noted my comment above regarding the use of `LEFT`... That is something worth considering else your `SEARCH` and `FIND` will fail for something like this `@BURT`. Notice the `RT` in the username ;) (FALSE POSITIVES - As mentioned by @Gaffi below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Excel's `FIND` function. You can use this to identify the position of the `@`, then using a specified delimiter, match the end of the user name:

```
=MID(A1, FIND("@",A1), FIND(":",A1,FIND("@",A1)) - FIND("@",A1))
```

Where `A1` is the cell containing the tweet, and `":"` is your delimiter.

---

You can use the same feature to check for the existence of the `"RT"` identifier.

```
=FIND("RT",A1)>0
```

Which returns `TRUE` if `"RT"` is found. You may want to consider a search for `" RT "` (spaces), or some other variation, since there is no standard for using this in a tweet:

```
=OR(FIND("RT",A1)>0,FIND(" RT",A1)>0,FIND("RT ",A1)>0, FIND(" RT ",A1)>0)
```

But beware of false positives: `ART`, `START`, `ARTOO`, etc...

Additionally, your `"RT"` may be lower/upper/mixed case, in which case you'll want to normalize that search:

```
=OR(FIND("RT",UPPER(A1))>0,FIND(" RT",UPPER(A1))>0,FIND("RT ",UPPER(A1))>0, FIND(" RT ",UPPER(A1))>0)
```

My `OR` check is different than the `0/1` check you say you already have, so you can jsut add `IF` to that to convert to the `0/1` as needed:

```
=IF(OR(FIND("RT",A1)>0,FIND(" RT",A1)>0,FIND("RT ",A1)>0, FIND(" RT ",A1)>0),1,0)
```

---

Once you know you have the RT check correct, and your second column is filled properly, you can add to my original formula:

Case for **1** in 2nd column:

```
=IF(B1=1,MID(A1, FIND("@",A1), FIND(":",A1,FIND("@",A1)) - FIND("@",A1)),"")
```

Case for **0** in 2nd column:

```
=IF(B1=0,MID(A1, FIND("@",A1), FIND(":",A1,FIND("@",A1)) - FIND("@",A1)),"")
```